# How to append multiple appender references in Log4j2?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I know in log4j you could use multiple appenders by doing something like:

```
log4j.logger.com.x=DEBUG, append1, append2
```

but what would the equivalence be in log4j2?

Would it be this:

```
logger.com.x.level = DEBUG
logger.com.x.appenderRefs = append1, append2
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not provide in your example, what are the types of appenders append1 and append2, but this is important, when you are using the properties file. Let's say the appenders are defined as following:

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = append1
...
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = append2
...
```

Loggers should be something like this:

```
logger.console.name = com.x
logger.console.level = debug
logger.console.additivity = false
logger.console.appenderRef.console.ref = append1

logger.rolling.name = com.x
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = append2
```

I am suggesting this configuration according to the properties file configuration example in the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties). I am not doing this way and prefer the xml format. I recommend you to consider moving to xml format. Most of examples in the log4j2 documentation are for xml configuration format. 
In case of xml, loggers configuration is much compact and is just like this:

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.x" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appenderRef ref="append1" />
        <appenderRef ref="append2" />
    </Logger>
    ...
</Loggers>
```

Comment: I agree that the Log4j 2 XML configuration is much simpler and better documented than Log4j 1.2. Most of the doc examples use XML so it will be much easier to solve problems (find similar configurations, get support) when you use the XML configuration format.

Comment: ok thank you, so in your middle block you are adding the two appenders to  one/the same logger, right?

Comment: Yes. You can add multiple appenders for the same logger in such manner. You can provide different loglevel to a particular appenderRef.

Comment: The provided properties example is misleading as it will not work as expected. You will actually overwrite the 1st defined logger _"logger.console.name = com.x"_ with the 2nd logger _"logger.rolling.name = com.x"_ so only the 2nd logger will be active. To add the 2nd appender to the logger, just add a new appenderRef property for the initial logger: _logger.console.appenderRef.appender2.ref = append2_

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a quite old question, but I found a solution by using the following syntax (using your example):

```
logger.com.x.appenderRef.app1.ref = append1
logger.com.x.appenderRef.app2.ref = append2
```

In this way everything worked fine.